# How to sort data using Data step in SAS

Tags: sas, datastep

I want to sort data in SAS data step. What exactly I mean is: the work of proc sort should be done in data step. Is there any solution?

Comment: Would love to know why you would want to do such a thing.

Comment: Just got idea. There is no need to do like this in complicated way. But out of enthusiasm and anxiety I want to know: is it possible in data step. I searched in google but I didn't find any answer so I posted here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're looking for a data-step only solution, you can do the work of `PROC SORT` with a [hash table](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lecompobjref/69740/HTML/default/viewer.htm#titlepage.htm). The caveat is that you need enough memory to do it.

If you want to do a simple sort, you would load the hash table with the `ordered:'yes'` option and output it to a new table. By default, `ordered:yes` will sort the data in ascending order. You can specify `descending` as well.

**Simple Sort**

```
data _null_;

    /* Sets up PDV without loading the table */
    if(0) then set sashelp.class;

    /* Load sashelp.class into memory ordered by Height. Do not remove duplicates. */
    dcl hash sortit(dataset:'sashelp.class', ordered:'yes', multidata:'yes');

        sortit.defineKey('Height');     * Order by height;
        sortit.defineData(all:'yes');   * Keep all variables in the output dataset;

    sortit.defineDone();

    /* Output to a dataset called class_sorted */
    sortit.Output(dataset:'class_sorted');
run;
```

**De-duping**

To remove duplicates, do the exact same operation, except remove the `multidata` option. In the below table, observations (8, 9) and (15, 16) are duplicates of each other. Observations 9 and 16 will be eliminated.

```
data _null_;

    /* Sets up PDV without loading the table */
    if(0) then set sashelp.class;

    /* Load sashelp.class into memory ordered by Height. Do not keep duplicates. */
    dcl hash sortit(dataset:'sashelp.class', ordered:'yes');

        sortit.defineKey('Height');     * Order by height;
        sortit.defineData(all:'yes');   * Keep all variables in the output dataset;
    sortit.defineDone();

    /* Output to a dataset called class_sorted */
    sortit.Output(dataset:'class_sorted');
run;
```

Answer (score 7):

Stu beat me to it, but provided that your dataset contains a unique key, and you can fit the whole thing in memory, you can use a hash sort, e.g.:

```
data _null_;
  if 0 then set sashelp.class;
  declare hash h(dataset:"sashelp.class",ordered:"a");
  rc = h.definekey("age","sex","name");
  rc = h.definedata(ALL:'yes');
  rc = h.definedone();
  rc = h.output(dataset:"class_sorted");
  stop;
run;
```

If you are really determined to avoid using any built-in sort methods, a particularly silly approach is to load the whole dataset into a series of temporary arrays, sort the arrays using a hand-coded algorithm, and export again:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79952/quicksort-in-sas-for-sorting-datasets

Answer (score 3):

There is solution in use proc ds2.

```
/*Just prepare dataset, because DS2 responds with an error on libraries like sashelp. */
data sql_prep;
set sashelp.class;
run;

/*Delete test dataset before ds2 func, to avoid errors*/
proc datasets nodetails nolist;
delete test;
run;

proc ds2;

data test;
   method run();
      set {select * from sql_prep order by Weight};
   end;
enddata;
run;
quit;
```

More [info](http://support.sas.com/kb/51/043.html) about ds2 errors with sashelp libs.

[Appendix](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=ds2ref&docsetTarget=p0htt17wcsy0sun0z7xzxn2x8q4f.htm&docsetVersion=9.4) into ds2 docs, about sql in ds2.